# Comparing the ratio of two values to 1

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm working via a basic 'Programming in C' book.

I have written the following code based off of it in order to calculate the square root of a number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float absoluteValue (float x)
{
    if(x < 0)
        x = -x;

    return (x);
}

float squareRoot (float x, float epsilon)
{

    float guess = 1.0;

    while(absoluteValue(guess * guess - x) >= epsilon)
    {
        guess = (x/guess + guess) / 2.0;
    }

    return guess;
}


int main (void)
{
    printf("SquareRoot(2.0) = %f\n", squareRoot(2.0, .00001));
    printf("SquareRoot(144.0) = %f\n", squareRoot(144.0, .00001));
    printf("SquareRoot(17.5) = %f\n", squareRoot(17.5, .00001));

    return 0;
}
```

An exercise in the book has said that the current criteria used for termination of the loop in `squareRoot()` is not suitable for use when computing the square root of a very large or a very small number.

Instead of comparing the difference between the value of x and the value of guess^2, the program should compare the ratio of the two values to 1. The closer this ratio gets to 1, the more accurate the approximation of the square root.

If the ratio is just guess^2/x, shouldn't my code inside of the while loop:

```
guess = (x/guess + guess) / 2.0;
```

be replaced by:

```
guess = ((guess * guess) / x ) / 1 ; ?
```

This compiles but nothing is printed out into the terminal. Surely I'm doing exactly what the exercise is asking?

Comment: Finding a ratio is just division, i.e. the `/` operator.

Comment: As a side note - when ratio of `x` and `y` is `1`, then `x` equals `y`...

Comment: How about `absoluteValue(guess * guess - x) >= epsilon*x` ?

Comment: Please, add the last line `return 0;` to your `main`, in order to conform to the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the ratio just do (guess * guess / x) that could be either higher or lower than 1 depending on your implementation. Similarly, your margin of error (in percent) would be absoluteValue((guess * guess / x) - 1) * 100

All they want you to check is how close the square root is. By squaring the number you get and dividing it by the number you took the square root of you are just checking how close you were to the original number.

```
Example: 
sqrt(4) = 2 
2 * 2 / 4 = 1 (this is exact so we get 1 (2 * 2 = 4 = 4))
margin of error = (1 - 1) * 100 = 0% margin of error

Another example:
sqrt(4) = 1.999 (lets just say you got this)
1.999 * 1.999 = 3.996
3.996/4 = .999 (so we are close but not exact)

To check margin of error:
.999 - 1 = -.001
absoluteValue(-.001) = .001
.001 * 100 = .1% margin of error
```

Comment: Okay thank you, so now I know how to get the ratio, 

Shouldn't my code inside of the while loop:

`guess = (x/guess + guess) / 2.0;`

be replaced by: `guess = ((guess * guess) / x ) / 1 ;` ?

This compiles but nothing is printed out into the terminal. Surely I'm doing exactly what the exercise is asking?

Answer (score 0):

How about applying a little algebra?  Your current criterion is:

|*guess*<sup>2</sup> - *x*| >= *epsilon*

You are elsewhere assuming that *guess* is nonzero, so it is algebraically safe to convert that to

|1 - *x* / *guess*<sup>2</sup>| >= *epsilon* / *guess*<sup>2</sup>

*epsilon* is just a parameter governing how close the match needs to be, and the above reformulation shows that it must be expressed in terms of the floating-point spacing near *guess*<sup>2</sup> to yield equivalent precision for all evaluations.  But of course that's not possible because *epsilon* is a constant.  This is, in fact, exactly why the original criterion gets less effective as *x* diverges from 1.

Let us instead write the alternative expression

|1 - *x* / *guess*<sup>2</sup>| >= *delta*

Here, *delta* expresses the desired precision in terms of the spacing of floating point values in the vicinity of 1, which is related to a fixed quantity sometimes called the "machine epsilon".  You can directly select the required precision via your choice of *delta*, and you will get the same precision for all `x`, provided that no arithmetic operations overflow.

Now just convert that back into code.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest a different point of view.

As this method `guess_next = (x/guess + guess) / 2.0;`, once the initial approximation is *in the neighborhood*, the number of [bits of accuracy doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton.27s_iterative_method).  Example `log2(FLT_EPSILON)` is about -23, so 6 iterations are needed.  (Think 23, 12, 6, 3, 2, 1)

The trouble with using `guess * guess` is that it may vanish, become 0.0 or infinity for a non-zero `x`.

To form a quality initial guess:

```
assert(x > 0.0f);
int expo;
float signif = frexpf(x, &expo);
float guess = ldexpf(signif, expo/2);
```

Now iterate N times (e.g. 6),  (N based on `FLT_EPSILON`, `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` or `FLT_DIG`.)

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    guess = (x/guess + guess) / 2.0f;
}
```

The cost of perhaps an extra iteration is saved by avoiding an expensive termination condition calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If code wants to compare `a/b` nearest to 1.0f

Simply use some epsilon factor like 1 or 2.

```
float a = guess;
float b = x/guess;
assert(b);
float q = a/b;
#define FACTOR (1.0f /* some value 1.0f to maybe 2,3 or 4 */) 
if (q >= 1.0f - FLT_EPSILON*N && q <= 1.0f + FLT_EPSILON*N) {
  close_enough();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First lesson in numerical analysis: for floating point numbers `x+y` has the potential for large relative errors, especially when the sum is near zero, but `x*y` has very limited relative errors.